# Add new admin menu under catalog section in opencart

Tags: menu, admin, catalog, opencart-3

I am using opencart 3.0.2.0 version. I need to add a new menu under the catalog section in the admin panel. I have added the new menu in common/column_left controller. But it's not reflecting on the left side menu.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue? I am still not able to find the solution for this.

Comment: i have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because admin theme is generated to the modification template you should refresh your modification in **Extension > Modifications > refresh button** at the top right.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I've tried to refresh the cache and modifications, this didn't help.

For me, the problem was with permission. You just don't have permission to the newly created section.

**$this->user->hasPermission** function call return false and we don't see the new menu item.

Just go to **System->Users->User Groups** and give yourself permission.